# hide and show after some time

Tags: jquery, html

I have above div but i want to hide them  and show each on interval time

I want them to be hidden by default when the page is opened

and then each should show after some time when page is loaded

```js
    
          $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#do_1').delay(1000).show();
      $('#do_2').delay(2000).show();
      $('#do_3').delay(3000).show();
      $('#do_4').delay(4000).show();
      $('#do_5').delay(5000).show();
          });
```

```html
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 
        <div id=do_1 > do 1 </div> 
     <div id=do_2 > do 2 </div> 
     <div id=do_3> do 3 </div> 
     <div id=do_4 > do 4 </div> 
     <div id=do_5 > do 5 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.content').hide();
        $('#do_1').delay(1000).show(0);
        $('#do_2').delay(2000).show(0);
        $('#do_3').delay(3000).show(0);
        $('#do_4').delay(4000).show(0);
        $('#do_5').delay(5000).show(0);
      });
```

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Untitled Document</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id=do_1 class='content'> do 1 </div> 
    <div id=do_2 class='content'> do 2 </div> 
    <div id=do_3 class='content'> do 3 </div> 
    <div id=do_4 class='content'> do 4 </div> 
    <div id=do_5 class='content'> do 5 </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```